Examples of uniform spaces which are not metrizable
I'm studying uniform spaces with Bourbaki's book. There I found out that a uniformity is metrizable iff it is Hausdorff and the filter of entourages of the uniformity has a countable basis. However, he doesn't provide an example. So I'm looking for examples of uniform spaces which aren't metrizable. Thank you for your help!

A corresponding post on [mathoverflow.se]: Non metrizable uniform spaces.
